# XSRF-TOKEN being secured with HttpOnly in AngularJS + Spring Boot but not included in requests back

Tags: angularjs, security, spring-boot

Having the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie set with HttpOnly creates problem for Angular Framework in picking it up from the `document.cookie` function.

Is there any way around this? I cannot make the `XSRF-TOKEN` non HttpOnly
I thought that perhaps I can intercept every incoming request in Middle Tier (Spring Boot), check through the cookies and if it is a POST/PUT/DELETE request and it has `XSRF-TOKEN`, I shall add the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS accesses the cookies in a manner such as 'document.cookies...' i.e. via javascript itself, and in this case HttpOnly just won't work. You should regardless translate Spring cookies to something that angular expects and understands ('XSRF-TOKEN'). This can be done in a filter like this:

```
public class CsrfHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
    if (csrf != null) {
        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
        String token = csrf.getToken();
        if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
            cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
            cookie.setSecure(true);
            cookie.setPath(request.getContextPath() + "/");
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

}